# Pass "<" or ">" as parameter in Comparator

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, methods, comparator

I'm working on a method for sorting data which has two parameters:

> a generic `ArrayList` and an instance of `Comparator`.

```
public static <T> void insertionSort(ArrayList<T> array, Comparator<T> c) { ... }
```

I would like to let the user decide if sort in descending or ascending order. Can I do it by passing in some way the symbols to the `Comparator`? I'm asking this because I cannot add the other parameter to my function.

Comment: `Comparator c = "<".equals(order) ? lessComp : greaterComp` ? Using two comparators and simply write a getter logic based on the parameter. You can also use [`Comparator.reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) instead of writing two. But the idea is the same

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Pass `comparator` or `comparator.reversed()` based on user input.

Comment: You can write your own **Comparator** classes, one returns `first - second` and the other returns `second - first`.

Comment: @eneski This is incorrect because of int overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to let the user decide if sort in descending or ascending order.

The API user will make this decision by calling the method and passing an instance of [`Comparator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
insertionSort(list, Comparator.naturalOrder());
insertionSort(list, Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

No additional params are required.

---

If you are designing an app where the user inputs the desired order (I named it `input`), a simple ternary operator could be used:

```
insertionSort(list, ">".equals(input) ? naturalOrder() : reverseOrder());
```